# An honest die is rolled 5 times. What is the probability that you will roll NO 6's?

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

An honest die is rolled 5 times. What is the probability that you will roll NO 6's?

I now know you can use binomial theorem to get the correct answer but I am failing to see why my original method would not have worked...

I found the total # of ways you could roll zero 6's: $5^5$
(5 ways to roll no 6 on the first roll, 5 ways to roll the second roll, etc.)
and then divided it by the total number of ways to roll a die 5 times: $6^5$
(6 ways to roll the first roll, 6 ways to roll the second roll, etc.).

I got $0.40$.

Why is that incorrect?

Comment: What makes you think that is wrong?

Comment: You are correct that it is $\dfrac{5^5}{6^5}$.  You are incorrect to call that number $0.40$.  Use precise numbers when and where possible.  Do not approximate unless explicitly told to.

Comment: As for "*I can use binomial theorem but...*"  The calculation would have been identical... the only difference would be a redundant $\binom{5}{0}$ term and $(\frac{1}{6})^0$ term, both of which are simply $1$ and could have been omitted.

Comment: I would use the same method for calculating this probability. What makes you think that this approach is original?

Comment: @user original as in the first chosen method, not that the idea is an original one

Comment: Google "binomial distribution".

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is already mentioned in comments, however I would have reached it on a different approach.
The odds to score a 6 in one roll are 1/6 therefore the odds to score anything else but a 6 are 5/6.
Since the dice rolling is an event independent of previous or next roll, then the odds to score anything but 6 in 5 consecutive events is ${(\frac{5}{6})}^5$

Comment: Do not mix up the words "odds" and "probability."  They both convey the same information, however they are presented differently.  The odds of getting a 6 on a die in a throw is $1:5$... The *probability* of doing so is $\frac{1}{6}$.  The odds of getting no sixes in five throws is $3125:4651$.